# Scroll along a curve

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to get the effect of scrolling a uitableview along a curved path.  Basically it would be like a bulging tableview on the side of the screen as if it were the side of a large circle.  I don't want to use a graphic effect to warp the tableview since the text would become harder to read.

Items on the top and bottom would be closer to the screen edge than objects near the center.

Comment: Like this? http://www.gamecabinetsinc.com/images/ddr3.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.  Very rough demonstration here as proof of concept.

First the connection to myScrollView is already set up with an IBOutlet and hooked to a scrollview in a xib.
Then I set up the scrollview in viewDidLoad:

```
int scrollItems = 20;
viewSize = 120;
viewItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(myScrollView.frame.size.width, (viewSize*1.25)*scrollItems)];
for(int i = 0; i < scrollItems; i++){
    UIView *thisView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myScrollView.frame.size.width/2, i*(viewSize*1.25), viewSize, viewSize)];
    [thisView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];  // spaced out blue squares
    [myScrollView addSubview:thisView];
    [viewItems addObject:thisView];
}
[myScrollView setDelegate:self];
[myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 1)]; // to force initial items to curve
```

}

That puts the items in a scrollview along with a global NSMutableArray. They are evenly spaced out and the scrollview is sized correctly for them.  Right now the items are lined up straight down roughly in the center of my scrollview.  To give them a curve we add the following method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
float start = [scrollView contentOffset].y;    
float height = scrollView.frame.size.height;
float end = start + height;  // change so it doesn't scoot views past the end

float viewOffset, viewTop;

int index = 0;
for(UIView *thisView in viewItems){
    viewTop = thisView.frame.origin.y+thisView.frame.size.height;
    if((viewTop>start)&&(thisView.frame.origin.y<end)){ // our visible range
        viewOffset = thisView.frame.origin.y - start;
        CGRect tempFrame = thisView.frame;
        tempFrame.origin.x = 90 - sin((viewOffset / height)*4)*80;
        thisView.frame = tempFrame;
        index++;
    }
}
```

}

This basically uses a sine wave  to scoot each item in the visible range over by the proper amount. So the top and the bottom items are adjusted by almost nothing, and the center items are scooted furthest out.  Like half a sine wave turned sideways.

It actually runs really smooth as is on my 1st gen iPad. I really like it a lot.  A few ways to speed it up...  calculate exactly which views are in the content area and only touch those, right now I'm checking every item from first to last and it's a waste.  Also precaching the sin() values may be worthwhile.  Another thing is scrollViewDidScroll can update 2 or 3 times at the same position redoing everything when there's no visible changes so a lot of detailed items may have trouble refreshing often.

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the piece of code. But how did you find these numbers? (tempFrame.origin.x = 90 - sin((viewOffset / height)*4)*80)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that you need a custom class, with core animation. I don't know enough to make the bezier curve, but basically you want an overall view container that is filled with say 5 cell views. If you move up, the top view is 'removeFromSuperview-ed', and you add a new cell on the bottom. The four other cells are animated to the next defined position on the bezier curve. Shouldn't be too hard, I think the most that you'll need to figure out is the following:

curve animation - moving UIViews by x and y, scaling the views based on x movement (get smaller the farther up or down the curve)

functions to add and subtract cells

a function to display / add contents to each cell

a function to move the cells up and down

Ideally this would be self contained. See if you can find a custom cover flow like tutorial, I think this is similar with a different animation.

Comment: I'd rather not reinvent the whole tableview concept, seems like a lot of work to me.  Maybe instead there's a way to scoot each cell on the screen to the left then the right as it scrolls down and I could still use a tableview.

Comment: @ XenElement: Hey thanks for the post.  It got me thinking of other things besides a UITableView.  I've got a basic working prototype now with a UIScrollview. I'm going to clean it up a little bit and then post here and mark it solved.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't even think about using a scroll view. Congratulations on getting it to work! Also, it seems like a useful framework/object, so if you do get the chance to post it, go for it.